# Spring form validation - errors are not displayed

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have following situation: 
I try to create a simple form to edit information about a movie. Therefor I use spring mvc with jsp.

For the validation I use the JSR 303 hibernate implementation (hibernate-validator 4.2.0).

My problem is that if there are validation errors (BindResults hasErrors method returns true) I can only display the errors with

```
<form:errors path="*" />
```

and **not fieldspecific**. like with:

```
<form:errors path="title" />
```

I have no idea why but all errors are displayed in at the path="*" errortag, but none at the fieldspecific ones. The only errors which are displayed right to the field are some which brought an exception i.e.

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property runtime; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "")
```

the important parts of my jsp file look like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form commandName="movie">
    <fieldset>
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="formErrorBlock"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="title">Title:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="title"/>
                    <form:errors path="title" cssClass="formFieldError"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="runtime">Runtime:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="runtime"/><br />
                    <form:errors path="runtime" cssClass="formFieldError" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="imdbId">IMDB-ID:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="imdbId"/><br />
                    <form:errors path="imdbId" cssClass="formFieldError" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MovieController {

@Autowired
private MovieService _movieService;

//some other methods...

@RequestMapping(value="/movie/{pMovieId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap pModel, @PathVariable Integer pMovieId) {
    Movie movie = _movieService.getMovieById(pMovieId);

    pModel.addAttribute("movie", movie);

    return "edit/movie";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/movie/{pMovieId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String editMovieSave(@Valid Movie pMovie, BindingResult pResult, @PathVariable Integer pMovieId, ModelMap pModel) {
    Movie movie = _movieService.getMovieById(pMovieId);

    if(pResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "edit/movie";
    }

    //save

    //redirect to moviepage
    return "redirect:/movie/" + pMovieId;
}
```

}

and finally my movie class:

```
public class Movie implements Serializable{

private int _id;
@NotEmpty
@Size(min=3)
private String _title;
@NotEmpty
private String _filename;
@Pattern(regexp="tt+[0-9]{7}")
private String _imdbId;
@Min(value=1)
private int _runtime;

//getters and setters....
```

}

I know this question has been asked a lot of times before, but none of the answers worked with me.

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you try `<form:errors path="_title" cssClass="formFieldError"/>`

Comment: I would try to remove the _ in the class attribute name to be in camel case, I know that there is the getter but maybe there are accessed by reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by renaming the attributes (removing the underlines). However it was like "jpprade" said (maybe there are accessed by reflection).

For those who can't rename the class attributes (in case of some codingconventions, ...) can annotate the getter methods.